# When to use simplicial, singular and relative homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

From my understanding, basically, the homology groups of all basic objects (especially those which are fundamental polygon) can be found using the simplicial homology. But specifically, when should I use simplicial, singular, or relative homology? Is there any indication for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use relative homology within either simplicial or singular settings, so it is not a matter of using "simplicial, singular, or relative": "relative" doesn't fit in this group. ("Absolute" is the word to best contrast with "relative" in the world of homology.)

As far as simplicial vs. singular goes, simplicial is easier to compute and singular is better-behaved theoretically. With just the definitions you can compute the simplicial homology of the boundary of a 1-simplex, but you wouldn't want to compute the singular homology of $S^1$ just from the definitions. On the other hand, it's easy to show that singular homology is a topological invariant, but this is far from obvious for simplicial homology.

Comment: So does that mean, singular homology is much useful to prove theoretical results like if $X$ is path-connected, then $H_0(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ (but less practical?) I saw very few examples of computation using singular homology.

Comment: Once you have proved results like Mayer-Vietoris (for example) for singular homology, then you have access to better computational tools. You should also prove that simplicial and singular homology agree, so that you can switch back and forth.